# Kick command not working even though theres no error discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is the code for my kick command

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(context, member : discord.Member = None, *, reason=None):
    if user == None:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"**Kick**",
                              description=f"Kicks a member"
                                          f"\nUsage: -kick <user> <reason>")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    embed = discord.Embed(description = f"Kicked {member}", color = 0xf30e0e)
    embed.add_field(name='Reason', value=f'{reason}')
    await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You do not have the permissions to run this command")
```

When i use it it doesnt work and yet theres no errors, can someone explain why this isnt working?

Comment: you're blocking every error message except the missing permissions one. add a  `else: raise error` to the end of your error handler to see them properly. Also the error probably comes from the fact that you are using context instead of ctx as an argument for the command.

Comment: it was working before and when i mean error i mean theres no errors in the code

Answer (score 0):

I would sincerely recommend you learn Python before you learn discord.py

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member = None, *, reason=None):
    if user == None:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="**Kick**",
            description="Kicks a member\nUsage: -kick <user> <reason>"
            )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    embed = discord.Embed(description = f"Kicked {member}", color = 0xf30e0e)
    embed.add_field(name='Reason', value=f'{reason}')
    await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I'm not 100 percent sure if it was the issue as I cannot test, but you did not add "ctx" to your function, instead putting "context." You also had a lot of weird indentation, and (this doesn't cause any issues) random F strings for no reason.

You also were not getting any errors because your error catching function blocks all errors except a permission error, in which it logs in Discord rather than your console.

Comment: Can you remove your error handler (or replace it with the one Mark sent) and then tell me what error you receive? I can't help you much if you don't even know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Like other's have said, you're only allowing the bot to send a message if an error is a missing permission. Try adding the following:

```
@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You do not have the permissions to run this command")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandError): # If the command fails...
        print(error) # Print the error in the console
```

Then, try solving the error you receive in the console. :)